# Session reset problem on every page reload

Tags: httpsession

In my console page, I need to save the executed commands and show them to the users. For that I am using session variable, as every user will get different sessions. But the problem is that the session is recreated every time. So, I always end up in getting an empty value here,

```
ArrayList commands = (ArrayList)session.getAttribute("commands")==null?new ArrayList():(ArrayList)session.getAttribute("commands");
```

Eventhough, I updated the session variable as below,it is not working because the session is recreated on every page load.

```
String cmd = (String)request.getAttribute("text1");
commands.add(cmd);
session.setAttribute("commands",commands);
```

I found that the session is recreated by using,

```
<%= session.getId() %>
```

(every time different value obtained).
Is there a way to prevent session recreation using web.xml or anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found that the problem is cookies={false} in my context.xml file. When I change that to true it is working fine.